# How to write this query with two joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table

type

> ```
>     +----+-------+
>     | id | type  |
>     +----+-------+
>     |  1 | typeA |
>     |  2 | typeB |
>     |  3 | typeC |
>     +----+-------+
> ```

brand (contains brands and sub brands with parent brand id, like brandC is a sub brand of brandA)

> ```
> +----+--------+--------+
> | id | brand  | parent |
> +----+--------+--------+
> |  1 | brandA |     0  |
> |  2 | brandB |     0  |
> |  3 | brandC |     1  |
> +----+--------+--------+
> ```

equipment

> ```
> +----+-------+-------+
> | id | type  | brand |
> +----+-------+-------+
> |  1 |     1 |     2 |
> |  2 |     2 |     1 |
> |  3 |     3 |     3 |
> +----+-------+-------+
> ```

I wrote this query:

```
$query = "select
    a.id,
    b.type,
    c.brand

from
    equipment a
        join type b
            on a.type=b.id
        join brand c
            on a.brand=c.id
where
    a.id=3";
```

it shows me the result below:

> ```
> +----+--------+---------+
> | id | type   | brand   |
> +----+--------+---------+
> |  3 | typeC  | brandC  |
> +----+--------+---------+
> ```

How shall I modify my query to show the parent brand as well if a brand has a parent brand. for instance brandC is a sub brand of brandA. So my result should look like:

> ```
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> | id | type   | brand   | Parent Brand   |
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> |  3 | typeC  | brandC  | brandA         |
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> ```

and when there is no parent brand it leaves the cell blank

also How will I modify the above query to see all equipment with their brands and sub brands like below.

> ```
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> | id | type   | brand   | Parent Brand   |
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> |  1 | typeA  | brandB  |                |
> |  2 | typeB  | brandA  |                |
> |  3 | typeC  | brandC  | brandA         |
> +----+--------+---------+----------------+
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because not all brands have valid parents, you need a left outer join for the parent:

```
select e.id, t.type, b.brand, bp.brand as parentBrand
from equipment e join
     type t
     on e.type= t.id join
     brand b
     on e.brand = b.id left outer join
     brand bp
     on b.parent = bp.id
where e.id = 3;
```

I also changed the aliases to be abbreviations of the table names.  This makes the query much easier to follow.

Comment: There is no outer join that I know of in MySQL

Comment: @Neal . . . Then you do not know MySQL very well.  It supports `left outer join`.   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html.  (I am a bit old-fashioned in using `left outer join` rather than `left join`, but MySQL supports that too.)

Comment: Only thing MySQL doesn't support are full outer joins.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, it works as i wanted it where e.id is given ... for list of all equipment i used the query below and that worked well. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * FROM brands b
JOIN equipment e on e.brand = b.id -- match type to brand
JOIN types t on t.id = e.type -- get type names
JOIN brands p on p.id = b.parent; -- get parent brand
```